# pyautogui GIMP automation problems

Tags: python, pycharm, pyautogui

I'm doing some automation with GIMP as my test case. I need to launch the program and send mouse/keyboard actions to it. I'm using `subprocess.call()` to start the program and `pyautogui` to send mouse/keyboard actions.

```
import pyautogui
import subprocess

subprocess.call('gimp', shell=True)    
gimp_file = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('imgs/gimp_file.png', grayscale=True,region=(5, 28, 29, 19))

file_button_x, file_button_y = pyautogui.center(gimp_file)  
pyautogui.click(file_button_x, file_button_y, duration=0.75)
```

The issue I'm having is that the `pyautogui` part of code is never hit, the program appears to just hang. I've run trough the debugger in PyCharm and no variables are returned. If I run `subprocess.call('gimp')` in python console and the rest on the code in another console it does what it should. I think can be either time delay caused by program start or window focus; I've adding `time.sleep(5)` to address the former cause, but no affect. How I can address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.call()` will wait for the process to exit - which won't happen (unless you quit GIMP), nor do you want it to wait. You should use `subprocess.Popen()`, with `stdin` set to `subprocess.DEVNULL` and `stdout/stderr` either left alone or also redirected to `DEVNULL`. This will allow your program to proceed to the `pyautogui` lines, while GIMP is running.

NOTE that gimp displays a splash screen, so you might need to wait a bit before you attempt to find its window and 'click' in it.